# Apple Push Notifications services (APNS) with Twitter trigger

Tags: ios, node.js, twitter, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I would like to send a `remote notification` to my `iOS` app whenever I tweet from my `Twitter` account. How do I go about this?

I know how to code for iOS but do not know anything related to `server-side coding`, so specific instructions would be very helpful :)

I have seen there is a paid service `PushWoosh` that has this functionality, but I don't want to `pay $40/month` for something I cannot customize.

Comment: I suggest to you to study first how to create a server-side coding. I've seen that you have tagged apns-php on your post so maybe studying php will be a perfect way to start. But for me I will just do it on nodejs. You can use nodejs twitter module to search for tweets and node-apn module to do push notifications.

Comment: Thanks @MarkAngeloHernandez . I definitely want to use modules because I want a quick way to do this. I will look into using nodejs. Thank you for your suggestion.